# How to fill column in pandas.DataFrame using data from another pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the first pandas.DataFrame

```
        first_key  second_key
0               0           1
1               0           1
2               0           2
3               0           3
4               0           3
```

and also the second pandas.DataFrame

```
              key      status
0               1       'good'
1               2        'bad'
2               3       'good'
```

And I want to get the following pandas.DataFrame

```
        first_key  second_key  status
0               0           1  'good'
1               0           1  'good'
2               0           2   'bad'
3               0           3  'good'
4               0           3  'good'
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by Series created from second `DataFrame`:

```
df['status'] = df['second_key'].map(df1.set_index('key')['status'])
print (df)
   first_key  second_key  status
0          0           1  'good'
1          0           1  'good'
2          0           2   'bad'
3          0           3  'good'
4          0           3  'good'
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `pd.DataFrame.join`

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('key'), on='second_key')

   first_key  second_key  status
0          0           1  'good'
1          0           1  'good'
2          0           2   'bad'
3          0           3  'good'
4          0           3  'good'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `merge()` method:

```
In [75]: d1.merge(d2.rename(columns={'key':'second_key'}))
Out[75]:
   first_key  second_key  status
0          0           1  'good'
1          0           1  'good'
2          0           2   'bad'
3          0           3  'good'
4          0           3  'good'
```

`.map()` method shown in @jezrael's answer is more preferrable (and more efficient) if you want to add a single column. Use `.merge()` method if you need to add multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function (rather than the `merge` method).

```
In [16]: merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", left_on="second_key", right_on="key")

In [17]: merged.drop("key", axis=1, inplace=True)

In [18]: merged
Out[18]: 
   first_key  second_key status
0          0           1   good
1          0           1   good
2          0           2    bad
3          0           3   good
4          0           3   good

In [19]:
```

IMHO, using the function makes the transformation slightly more explicit. But this is obviously a matter or taste...